# Jquery None Stop background-position

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create a simple moving background.It works for first time, however I do not know how to run the none stop animate function.
Can you pleae let me know how I can make it to work continously? It would be great if you let me know how to use the jquery easing functions with this which can make the moving much smoother.

Here is my code:
1- Html:

```
<div class="wave"></div>
```

2- CSS:

```
.wave{ background:url(http://www.publicspace.net/images/vitamin/cloud.png) top left no-repeat;
 width:70px;
 height:70px;
```

}

3- jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.wave').css({'background-position': '0px 0px'}). 
animate({'background-position': '-160px 0px'}); 
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

```
     $(document).ready(function(){


        doit();


        });

function doit(){
        $('.wave').css({'background-position': '0px 0px'}). 

        animate({'background-position': '-160px 0px'},doit()); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but there is gaps between loading for the second time and more, can you olease let me know how to fix it?